# How do I determine the "best" parametric equation for lines?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, parametric

Let's say I have to determine the **vector equation** and the **parametric equation** for:
$$
2x_1+3x_2=5
$$

**How do I determine it the "best" way?** I.e. avoiding fractions etc.? Because the answer is:
$$
x_1=1+3t, x_2=1-2t
$$
How do find that it's a "good idea" to put one of the parameters to 1-2t so the other one becomes nice and neat?

Comment: You can always eliminate fractions at the end by multiplying through by the least common denominator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $2(x_1-1)=3(1-x_2)$

$\iff\dfrac{x_1-1}3=\dfrac{1-x_2}2=t$(say)